# Why do we take this approximattion in optics?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, approximations

I am studying optics, particularly diffraction by circular lenses. I am following Pedrotti's book. To derive the lateral magnification for such lenses, the author makes the following drawing, and uses the approximations $\sin(\theta_1) \approx \tan(\theta_1)$, and the same for $\theta_2$, combined with Snell's law to write:

$$\dfrac{h_o}{s} n_1 = \dfrac{h_i}{s'} n_2 \implies m = \dfrac{h_i}{h_0} = \dfrac{n_1 s'}{n_2 s}.$$

[image: Picture from Pedrotti]

Here $s = \overline{OV}, s' = \overline{VI}$. We can conclude from this that for a plane lens, with $s' = n_2 / n_1 s, \ m = 1$, as expected. But if we name the tip of the $h_0$ arrow $A$, and the tip of the $h_i$ arrow $B$, then $ACO \sim CIB  $, which gives: $$\dfrac{h_0}{R+s} = \dfrac{h_i}{s'-R}, \implies m = \dfrac{s' - R }{s + R}$$
which also goes to $1$ for plane lenses, which makes sense (provided we accordingly change the sign of the denominator). Why not use this formula, if it is more accurate for a larger range of angles?

Comment: One adicional benefict of using this formula would be that is the same for reflection calculations, one would just obtain $s'$ diferently. But since the formulas for $m$ for reflection and refraction are diferent, I probably made a mistake somewhere

Comment: Are you looking for an answer beyond "good approximations simplify the math by removing unnecessary complications without losing much accuracy?"

Comment: Perhaps not, but this particular result makes no approximations on $\theta$, and my main point of confusion is the approximation on those angles. If we call $VCA = \varphi$, I understand approximating that to be generally small for good approximation, but why for $\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* know *a priori* the value of $s'$ because that is the image coordinate. So you have to find it as a function of $n_1$, $n_2$, $R$ and $s$. You didn't read the previous part. At the beginning of section 8 (Refraction at a Spherical Surface) he has to use another pair of rays to probe the relationship:

$$\frac{n_1}{s} + \frac{n_2}{s'} = \frac{n_2-n_1}{R}$$

And in the process he *has to* use the paraxial approximation $\sin \theta_i \approx \tan \theta_i$ and $\sin \theta_i \approx \theta_i$ for each angle. So, if you first need to assume that in order to find $s'$, then you can simplify the amplification formula because you already are under that hypothesis.

You might still are reluctant to use this approximation, but otherwise there is no analytic formula to find $s'$. Besides, usually in the practice this is not a problem. For example if you use glasses your eyes won't 'focus' on the rays that form a huge angle with the lens since you don't make a big angle in order to look—unless you are a squint, but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks Pizzaguy07! and welcome to the stack exchange.  +1 from NN